How can I install another mySQL ODBC connector than the 3.51 in VB6?
How can I install another mySQL ODBC connector than the 3.51 in VB6. I download already recent connectors because I need TLS1.2 protocol. Many thanks!
ConString = "" & "Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; " & strServer & ";Port=" & mySQL_Port & ";database=" & mySQL_Database & "; User=" & mySQL_User & ";Password=" & mySQL_Password & ";Option=3;"
I want to use the MySql ODBC 5.1 Driver insted the 3.51 but I don't know how to install in the VB6 !
I tried to install it in VB6 several times but without success.
